# Get emoji informations from a message in discord.js

Tags: bots, discord, discord.js

I want to see if a emoji in a message is animated or not. All I have is just the name and ID of the emoji, obtained from the message.content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Animated emojis usually appears with an `a` before the emoji name on the message content.

- <`a`:emoji_name:12345678912> - is animated.
- <:emoji_name:12345678912> - is not animated.

You can get whether the emoji is animated using this regex:

`/<(a?):(\w+):(\d+)>/`

- Group 1: if is not empty, it is animated.
- Group 2: emoji name.
- Group 3: emoji ID.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this using the [`.animated`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Emoji?scrollTo=animated) property of Emoji

Here is an example how you could do it:

```
const reaction = message.guild.emojis.get("ID OF YOUR EMOJI");
if (reaction.animated) return console.log('THIS EMOJI IS ANIMATED')
```